# Load More functionality using Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to enable a functionality of 'Loading more' in my website.
Since i'm fetching my data from remote DB using Spring JPA, I was wondering how would I implement such feature in Spring?

Basically, what I want to do, is to load only 100 records on the first REST call. And if the user clicks 'Load More', then I perform a new call for another 100 records from the last index I stopped (means records 101-200), and so on.

I can send start and end index via HTTP POST if needed. this is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface IStatusRepository extends CrudRepository<StatusDAO,String> {

    List<StatusDAO> getStatusByIdAndFqhnIn(String id, List<String> filteredHostList);

}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Pageable` or `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>` to fulfill your requirements.
By having it extend `PagingAndSortingRepository,` we get f`indAll(Pageable pageable)` and `findAll(Sort sort)` methods for paging and sorting.

Once we have our repository extending from PagingAndSortingRepository, we just need to:

1. Create or obtain a PageRequest object, which is an implementation of
   the Pageable interface
2. Pass the PageRequest object as an argument to the repository method
   we intend to use

Example:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Integer> {

    List<Product> findAllByPrice(double price, Pageable pageable);
}
```

---

```
Pageable firstPageWithTwoElements = PageRequest.of(0, 2);

Pageable secondPageWithFiveElements = PageRequest.of(1, 5);
```

---

```
Page<Product> allProducts = productRepository.findAll(firstPageWithTwoElements);

List<Product> allTenDollarProducts = 
  productRepository.findAllByPrice(10, secondPageWithFiveElements);
```

[Paging and Sorting Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html) [Refer 1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) [Refer 2](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/SpringBootUsingPagination)